# Correct way to use Axios with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, axios, react-typescript

I have an error in my application that I can't seem to solve.
I use `axios` with `TypeScript`.
Here's a code example of what I try to do:

```
export const fetchTransactions = (PageNum: number, PageSize: number, Context_id: number) => new Promise<Transaction[]> (async (resolve, reject) => {

  try
  {
    const response = await axios.post<AxiosResponse<Transaction[]>>(FETCH_TRANSACTIONS_URL, {PageNum, PageSize, Context_id})
    const {transactions} = response.data
    resolve(transactions)
  }
  catch (error) {
    reject(error.response);
  }
})
```

Now the error that I get for this `const {transactions} = response.data` is the following :
[image]

How can I remove this error? What should be the correct type of the response?

Comment: The `{name}` syntax is object destructuring syntax. It's meant to make it easier to get a property from an object into a variable. `response.data` is likely an array of `Transaction`s (since that's how you define it), which generally doesn't have a property named `transactions`. I think what you want is `const transactions = response.data;`, without the brackets.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks for the reply. `response.data` is actually an object of type `{transactions: [] }` that's why I do object destructing.

Comment: Then the type of the response should be `AxiosResponse<{ transactions: Transaction[] }>` so that the `transactions` property exists according to TypeScript.

Comment: @HereticMonkey do you mean, `axios.post<AxiosResponse<{transactions: Transaction[]}>>` or `axios.post<{transactions: Transaction[]}>` ? The former didn't work - I got the same error, the latter did work.

Comment: Then I meant the latter ;). I don't use axios, so I was guessing. You just need something in there that has `transactions` as a property.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, I use axios with Typescript this way

```
const fetchTransactions = (PageNum: number, PageSize: number, Context_id: number): Promise<Transaction[]> =>
  axios
    .post<Transaction[]>(FETCH_TRANSACTIONS_URL, {PageNum, PageSize, Context_id})
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return response.data;
      }
      throw new Error(response.status.toString());
    })
    .catch(({ response }) => {
      throw new Error(response.status);
    });
```

Comment: At the `then()` the value of `response.status` will always be 2XX, never 300 or 500. You need to move the status code check to the `catch` block. See https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors

Answer (score 0):

I did not want to type-out this very large JSON structure in Typescript.
So I used AxiosPromise and it worked:

```
export class MyComponent {
  public sales: any;

  constructor() {
    const response = await axios.get<AxiosPromise>( base_api_url + '/sales')
    console.log(response.data);
    this.sales = response.data;
  }
}
```

}